# git: can't seems to re base only a part of branch

Tags: git

So my project looks like this :

```
A--B--C--D master
      \
       \-E--F--G--H topic 1
```

And i would like to re base a part of the topic branch so that it looks like this :

```
A--B--C--D master
       \  \-G--H topic 2
        \-E--F topic 1
```

Is it possible and if yes can you guys help me ? Thank you !

Comment: You could just cherry pick...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rebase --onto` here to handle the `topic2` branch.  First, create a `topic2` branch from `topic1`:

```
git checkout -b topic2
```

Then use `rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto D F
```

To handle the `topic1` branch, just switch back to it and then do a hard reset to remove the top 2 commits:

```
git checkout topic1
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you `cherry-pick` G and H onto topic 2, then `git reset` topic 1 back to F?

Starting from `master`, I'd run the following:

`git checkout -b topic-2`

`git cherry-pick G`

`git cherry-pick H`

`git checkout topic-1`

`git reset F --hard`